# Geometry sample tests

Tags: geometry

I am teaching intro to Geometry using Moise and Downs textbook.  It is an excellent text but somewhat old.

Does anyone know if there are sample tests that are available for use with this textbook?

Comment: Not sure why downvoted.  Seems like an on topic question, right in the center of "math educators".

Comment: My suggestion is to write your own (if you have time) and keep it close to the given problems. They are described as stumpers anyway.  So I think if you are a little more formulaic on the tests, that is a good move (harder to produce under pressure).  You could also just use an alternate test for problems.  Again, it does not matter if they are a little easier than the Moise problems as the kids are under exam and time pressure.